# Strategy of Bishop and Knight Checkmate

Tags: endgame, strategy, checkmate, knights, bishops

I am a beginner when it comes to handling `King, Bishop and Knight` vs `King`for a checkmate.

Can I know what is the strategy to follow in the steps that ultimately leads to the checkmate?

This is something even the Woman Grand Master Anna Ushenina failed to make it through unfortunately. Maybe she was not able to concentrate. [Bishop and Knight drawn match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFF5ibgB6eA)

Comment: Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_and_knight_checkmate

Comment: And then try this: http://www.chessgym.net